Are Markov chains $X_{t+r}$, $X_{2t}$ and $(X_t; X_{t+1})$?
I'm trying to solve a problem. Let $X_n$ be a Markov chain with values in the set $H$. Will there be Markov chains

$X_{n+r}$, where $r > 0$ is fixed,
$X_{2n}$,
$(X_n, X_{n+1}) \in H^2$?

The first is obviously true, because if we have an event $A$ and a partition $(B_i)$ of some event $B$, that $\forall i \space \mathbb{P}(A |B_i) =p$, then $\mathbb{P} (A | B) = p$. And in our case, we split the event $(X_{t+r} = a_t; ...; X_r = a_0)$ by the values $X_0, ..., X_{r-1}$. But the other points don't look so obvious. It seems that the second is incorrect and some simple example can be built, but I can't find it. I will be grateful for any help.

Since $X_k$ is a Markov chain we have
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_{2n+1}=k\mid X_{2n}=i_0, X_{2n-2}=i_2,\dots)
=\mathbb{P}(X_{2n+1}=k\mid X_{2n}=i_0)
$$
Next,
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_{2n+2}=i\mid X_{2n}=i_0, X_{2n-2}=i_2,\dots)
=
\sum_{k\in H}\mathbb{P}(X_{2n+2}=i, X_{2n+1}=k\mid X_{2n}=i_0, X_{2n-2}=i_2,\dots)
=
\sum_{k\in H}\mathbb{P}(X_{2n+2}=i\mid X_{2n+1}=k,X_{2n}=i_0, X_{2n-2}=i_2,\dots)\mathbb{P}(X_{2n+1}=k\mid X_{2n}=i_0, X_{2n-2}=i_2,\dots)
=
\sum_{k\in H}\mathbb{P}(X_{2n+2}=i\mid X_{2n+1}=k,X_{2n}=i_0)
\mathbb{P}(X_{2n+1}=k\mid X_{2n}=i_0)
=
\sum_{k\in H}\mathbb{P}(X_{2n+2}=i, X_{2n+1}=k\mid X_{2n}=i_0)
=
\mathbb{P}(X_{2n+2}=i\mid X_{2n}=i_0)
$$
so $X_{2n}$ is Markov too.
